# Modifying an NSMutableArray inside a loop

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an `NSMutableArray` filled with `Task` objects. I want to be able to delete those whose `completed` property are set to `YES`

```
    NSMutableArray *allTasks = (NSMutableArray *)[[TaskStore defaultStore] allTasks];

    NSMutableArray *completedTasks;

    for (Task *task in allTasks) {
        if ([task completed]) {
            [completedTasks addObject:task];
        }
    }

    [allTasks removeObjectsInArray:completedTasks];
```

While debugging I noticed that the `completedTasks` array is always empty. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the completedTasks :

```
NSMutableArray *completedTasks = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the array before you can use it, the initializing actually creates your array object -

To do this add This Line to create an autoreleased array (which means you dont have to release it)

```
NSMutableArray *completedTasks = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Or

```
 NSMutableArray *completedTasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

But then you will have to release it by yourself `[completedTasks release]` when you are not using it any moere (unless you are using ARC).

This will create your array object.

Shani

Comment: it could be both,  [NSMutableArray array] is an autorelesed one.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized completedTasks.  You need to add this:

```
NSMutableArray *completedTasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: I have initialized it, just didn't include that part of the code.

Comment: Have you verified that the for loop is actually looping through?

Comment: Yes, I stepped through it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

from NSMutableArray documentation :

> This method assumes that all elements in otherArray respond to hash and isEqual:.

You can try :

```
 [allTasks filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completed = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]]
```